# Running a logistic model in JAGS - Can you vectorize instead of looping over individual cases?

Tags: bayesian, jags

I'm fairly new to JAGS, so this may be a dumb question. I'm trying to run a model in JAGS that predicts the probability that a one-dimensional random walk process will cross boundary A before crossing boundary B. This model can be solved analytically via the following logistic model:

Pr(A,B) = 1/(1 + exp(-2 * (d/sigma) * theta))

where "d" is the mean drift rate (positive values indicate drift toward boundary A), "sigma" is the standard deviation of that drift rate and "theta" is the distance between the starting point and the boundary (assumed to be equal for both boundaries).

My dataset consists of 50 participants, who each provide 1800 observations. My model assumes that d is determined by a particular combination of observed environmental variables (which I'll just call 'x'), and a weighting coefficient that relates x to d (which I'll call 'beta'). Thus, there are three parameters: beta, sigma, and theta. I'd like to estimate a single set of parameters for each participant. My intention is to eventually run a hierarchical model, where group level parameters influence individual level parameters. However, for simplicity, here I will just consider a model in which I estimate a single set of parameters for one participant (and thus the model is not hierarchical).

My model in `rjags` would be as follows:

```
model{
for ( i in 1:Ntotal ) {   
 d[i] <- x[i] * beta
 probA[i] <- 1/(1+exp(-2 * (d[i]/sigma) * theta )   )
 y[i] ~ dbern(probA[i])    
 }

 beta ~ dunif(-10,10)
 sigma ~ dunif(0,10)
 theta ~ dunif(0,10)
}
```

This model runs fine, but takes ages to run. I'm not sure how JAGS carries out the code, but if this code were run in R, it would be rather inefficient because it would have to loop over cases, running the model for each case individually. The time required to run the analysis would therefore increase rapidly as the sample size increases. I have a rather large sample, so this is a concern.

Is there a way to vectorise this code so that it can calculate the likelihood for all of the data points at once? For example, if I were to run this as a simple maximum likelihood model. I would vectorize the model and calculate the probability of the data given particular parameter values for all 1800 cases provided by the participant (and thus would not need the for loop). I would then take the log of these likelihoods and add them all together to give a single loglikelihood for the all observations given by the participant. This method has enormous time savings. Is there a way to do this in JAGS?

---

**EDIT**

Thanks for the responses, and for pointing out that the parameters in the model I showed might be unidentified. I should've pointed out that model was a simplified version. The full model is below:

```
model{
  for ( i in 1:Ntotal ) {
    aExpectancy[i] <- 1/(1+exp(-gamma*(aTimeRemaining[i] - aDiscrepancy[i]*aExpectedLag[i]) ) )
    bExpectancy[i] <- 1/(1+exp(-gamma*(bTimeRemaining[i] - bDiscrepancy[i]*bExpectedLag[i]) ) )
    aUtility[i] <- aValence[i]*aExpectancy[i]/(1 + discount * (aTimeRemaining[i]))
    bUtility[i] <- bValence[i]*bExpectancy[i]/(1 + discount * (bTimeRemaining[i]))
    aMotivationalValueMean[i] <- aUtility[i]*aQualityMean[i]
    bMotivationalValueMean[i] <- bUtility[i]*bQualityMean[i]
    aMotivationalValueVariance[i] <- (aUtility[i]*aQualitySD[i])^2 + (bUtility[i]*bQualitySD[i])^2
    bMotivationalValueVariance[i] <- (aUtility[i]*aQualitySD[i])^2 + (bUtility[i]*bQualitySD[i])^2
    mvDiffVariance[i] <- aMotivationalValueVariance[i] + bMotivationalValueVariance[i]
    meanDrift[i] <- (aMotivationalValueMean[i] - bMotivationalValueMean[i])
    probA[i] <- 1/(1+exp(-2*(meanDrift[i]/sqrt(mvDiffVariance[i])) *theta ) )
    y[i] ~ dbern(probA[i])
  }
```

In this model, the estimated parameters are `theta`, `discount`, and `gamma`, and these parameters can be recovered. When I run the model on the observations for a single participant (`Ntotal` = 1800), the model takes about 5 minutes to run, which is totally fine. However, when I run the model on the entire sample (45 participants x 1800 cases each = 78,900 observations), I've had it running for 24 hours and it's less than 50% of the way through. This seems odd, as I would expect it to just take 45 times as long, so 4 or 5 hours at most. Am I missing something?

Comment: What is "ages"? I would guess that you could get a reasonable effective sample size in a few minutes at worst from this model.

Comment: You can't vectorize `exp` in JAGS. But even if you could, I suspect it would not help--JAGS is written in C++ and there should not be the speed penalty to looping that there is in R. More importantly than speed, it seems like the parameters beta, sigma, and theta would not be identifiable, given that they enter the likelihood as a single product. Have you tried fitting the model on a small dataset with simulated parameters and response to see if can recover the parameters?

Answer (score 5):

I hope I am not misreading this situation (and I previously apologize if I am), but your question seems to come from a conceptual misunderstanding of how JAGS works (or WinBUGS or OpenBUGS for that matter).

Your program does not actually *run*, because what you wrote was not written in a *programming* language.  So vectorizing will not help.

You wrote just a description of your model, because JAGS' language is a *descriptive* one.

Once JAGS reads your model, it assembles a transition matrix to run a MCMC whose stationary distribution is the posteriori distribution of your parameters given your (observed) data.  JAGS does nothing else with your program.

All that time you have been waiting the program to run was actually waiting (and hoping) to reach relaxation time of your MCMC.

So, what is taking your program too long to run is that the resulting transition matrix must have bad relaxing properties or anything like that.

That is why vectorizing a program that is read and run only once will be of very little help.

So, your problem lies somewhere else.

I hope it helps and, if not, sorry.

All the best.

Comment: Quite thorough first answer. +1 for you sir.

Comment: Many thanks and I am glad my answer was usefull.   =)

Answer (score 2):

You can't vectorise in the same way that you would in R, but if you can group observations with the same probability expression (i.e. common d[i]) then you can use a Binomial rather than Bernoulli distribution which will help enormously. If each observation has a unique d[i] then you are stuck I'm afraid.

Another alternative is to look at Stan which is generally faster for large data sets like yours.

Matt

Answer (score -1):

thanks for the responses. Yes, you make a good point that the parameters in the model I showed might be unidentified.

I should've pointed out that model was a simplified version. The full model is below:

```
model{
  for ( i in 1:Ntotal ) {  

    aExpectancy[i] <- 1/(1+exp(-gamma*(aTimeRemaining[i] - aDiscrepancy[i]*aExpectedLag[i]) ) )
    bExpectancy[i] <- 1/(1+exp(-gamma*(bTimeRemaining[i] - bDiscrepancy[i]*bExpectedLag[i]) ) )

    aUtility[i] <- aValence[i]*aExpectancy[i]/(1 + discount * (aTimeRemaining[i]))
    bUtility[i] <- bValence[i]*bExpectancy[i]/(1 + discount * (bTimeRemaining[i]))

    aMotivationalValueMean[i] <- aUtility[i]*aQualityMean[i]
    bMotivationalValueMean[i] <- bUtility[i]*bQualityMean[i]
    aMotivationalValueVariance[i] <- (aUtility[i]*aQualitySD[i])^2 + (bUtility[i]*bQualitySD[i])^2
    bMotivationalValueVariance[i] <- (aUtility[i]*aQualitySD[i])^2 + (bUtility[i]*bQualitySD[i])^2

    mvDiffVariance[i] <- aMotivationalValueVariance[i] + bMotivationalValueVariance[i]
    meanDrift[i] <- (aMotivationalValueMean[i] - bMotivationalValueMean[i])
    probA[i] <- 1/(1+exp(-2*(meanDrift[i]/sqrt(mvDiffVariance[i])) *theta )   )
    y[i] ~ dbern(probA[i])    

  }

  theta ~ dunif(0,10)  
  discount ~ dunif(0,10)
  gamma ~ dunif(0,1)
}
```

In this model, the estimated parameters are `theta`, `discount`, and `gamma`, and these parameters can be recovered.

When I run the model on the observations for a single participant (`Ntotal = 1800`), the model takes about 5 minutes to run, which is totally fine.

However, when I run the model on the entire sample (*45 participants X 1800 cases each = 78,900 observations*), I've had it running for 24 hours and it's less than 50% of the way through.

This seems odd, as I would expect it to just take 45 times as long, so 4 or 5 hours at most. Am I missing something?

Comment: To add new information to your question, edit the original post (find the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32423334/edit) link at the bottom of your post), rather than posting it as an answer (unless of course you _are_ answering your own question). I've added your new info to your original post.

Comment: The author of the question included this answer in their edit in original question, however forgot to delete this answer, which is not a proper answer but, instead, an inclusion of new information abaout the problem and a new question at the end,